# PostgreSQL is missing after reboot

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am running Atlassian Jira software and using Postgresql as its database server.

We have a power interruption which turned off the host server and therefore the vm's didn't shut down correctly.

When rebooting the Jira machine, it wouldn't load Jira I forcefully started Jira to realize that it still wasn't connecting to the database.

When switching to user postgres and running `psql` I get the error

> Warning: No existing local cluster is suitable as a default target. Please see man_pg warpper(1) how to specify one.
>   Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client- package.

There were two versions of postgres on this Ubuntu 18.04 machine 9.5 and 10.

9.5 is installed in `/opt/PostgreSql/9.5`

10, well I don't have a clue where that is. the only place I can find anything that says 10 is in `/etc/postgres/main/10/`

the only "data" I can find was in `/opt/PostgreSql/9.5/data`.

When restarting the PostgresQL service was masked, so I ran

```
systemctl unmask postgresql.service.
```

I then ran

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

It doesn't look like it started it fully, just some dummy services of it.

I then try to do `sudo su postgres` then navigate to `/opt/PostgreSql/9.5/bin` and run `./pg_ctl start` but I get an error that says PGDATA isn't defined.

I don't know where to find that or what to do with it.

Is there a daemon or something I need to restart? Why is it saying that there is no version of PostgresQL installed? I am really lost here.

Comment: "*I get the error that says postgresql isn't installed*" - please **[edit]** your question and add the **exact** error message that you get.

Comment: I strongly suggest you do NOT go and run random commands. First, find what versions you have and the configuration settings (those are usually in some subdirectory under `/etc/`).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry I edited with the exact output

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ They weren't exactly random, It said that psql was masked so I unmasked it. I know that pg_ctl can start postgres so I gave that a shot. But thats about the extent of my postgresql knowledge.

Comment: Yes, sorry if my tone was offensive. I would first try running `pg_lsclusters` (it will just show the status of postgres instances. It's often available in Debian/Ubuntu installations)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ no worries it wasn't. I am on open book to learning this stuff. Well, i went to run     pg_lsclusters and I got an error that the command wasnt found. I had to sudo apt install postgresql-common. After running that I can run the command but the output is empty (no clusters). It's like postgres never even existed on this machine. Just to run psql I had to install postgresql utils

Comment: Are there any `postgresql.conf` files, either under `/opt/PostgreSql/9.5/` or `/etc/postgres/` or subdirectories? If yes, you can see the contents with a text editor (or cat) and find the data directories.

Comment: Other things to check are the logs (`/var/log/messages` and possibly under `/var/log/postgresql` or `/var/log/postgres`) for errors that will indicate what went wrong during restart.